# Is this code fragment well defined behaviour?

Tags: c, gcc, armv7

doing a study exercise i stumbled upon the following piece of code written for ARMv7 Architecture:

```
register char* reg_r0 asm ("r0");
*reg_r0 = putch(*reg_r0);
```

the function containing this code is called by an assembler routine and "r0" will contain some address pointing to some static variable. The code is compiled with gcc and -O0 and works as you would expect (it writes the return value of `putch` into that static variable mentioned before). By convention, return values are returned in R0, so I wondered if some compiler could dereference and write to the address contained in `reg_r0` after `putch` has returned and cause some access violation if that return value is not an address you are supposed to write to.

Comment: It uses compiler-extensions, so no, it cannot be well-defined by the C standard.

Comment: If you have to use full assembler functions instead of inline-assembler or - best - C, have to conform to the ABI.

Comment: You mean aside from the "dereferencing an uninitialised variable" aspect of `putch(*reg_r0)`, which is quite definitely undefined C behaviour?

Comment: @Notlikethat Well, good point. Now that you say it, I see that, too.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks, it's what I thought, just wanted to hear some other opinions.

Comment: Wow, that's funny, I'm going full Baader-Meinhoff right now.

Comment: Other than a serious run-on sentence, this is a reasonably well formed question.  Why the down vote?

Comment: If you want to be able to quote an official source, how about this (from gcc's [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html): _the following uses are explicitly not supported. If they appear to work, it is only happenstance ... Passing parameters to or from routines written in assembler (or other languages) using non-standard calling conventions._